# Can someone help me understand the recursion in the following code?

Tags: c, recursion

I'm a novice in recursion. Can somebody help me understand how the recursion works in the following code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
int f(int *p, int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) return 0;
    else return max(f(p+1,n-1),p[0]-p[1]);
}
int main()
{
   int a[] = {3,5,2,6,4};
   printf("%d", f(a,5));
}
```

Specifically, I am not understanding the recursion taking place in this line:

```
max(f(p+1,n-1),p[0]-p[1])
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @RobertColumbia,I not understanding the recursion taking in this line max(f(p+1,n-1),p[0]-p[1])

Comment: Run it in a debugger and step into the nested calls. Or just sprinkle some `printf`'s in there and see where that takes you.

Answer (score 2):

The function `f` takes an array and the size of that array, and recursively compares neighboring values, finally returning the maximum distance (numerical, non-absolute) between neighboring values. In your case, the function will return `3`, which represents the greatest distance of 3 between `5` and `2`. The difference between `2` and `6` in this case is `-4`, since absolute values are not being taken.

The recursive case is a little confusing because the call `f(p+1,n-1)` has two kinds of arithmetic. `p+1` is *pointer* arithmetic, while `n-1` is regular numerical arithmetic. `p+1` is simply advancing the array pointer to the next element, while `n-1` is decrementing the array size so that the function will end when there are no more elements to compare.

The base case says that if you have already checked all pairs, the highest distance is zero.

**Instrumented Code**

The following code is instrumented, including removing the `max()` usage and opting for a simple ternary expression to calculate the maximum difference. Functionally this should be the same as what was posted, but adds a `printf` statement both in the function and in `main()` to see addresses and values at those addresses. It should amplify what was described above.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int *p, int n)
{
    // no sense in checking zero or one element.
    if (n <= 1)
        return 0; // actually, this should be INT_MIN, but whatever

    // print this call-frame for the values we're interested in
    printf("p = %p, n = %d, p[0] = %d, p[1] = %d\n",
           (const void*)p, n, p[0], p[1]);


    int lhs = f(p+1,n-1); // recurse here
    int rhs = p[0] - p[1];

    // return the maximum of the two values
    return (lhs < rhs) ? rhs : lhs;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {3,5,2,6,4};
    printf("%p %d", (const void*)a, f(a,5));
}
```

**Output** (note: addresses will vary by system)

```
p = 0x7fff5fbff970, n = 5, p[0] = 3, p[1] = 5
p = 0x7fff5fbff974, n = 4, p[0] = 5, p[1] = 2
p = 0x7fff5fbff978, n = 3, p[0] = 2, p[1] = 6
p = 0x7fff5fbff97c, n = 2, p[0] = 6, p[1] = 4
0x7fff5fbff970 3
```

Note that the last line shows the base address of `a[]` in `main()`. The initial invoke of the function (top line) shows the same address. Note how the address adjusts based on the *pointer arithmetic* described earlier. That, coupled with the decreasing value of `n`, makes each recursive call look at a "shorter" sequence. In reality it is the same sequence; just starting from a different position and with a different element count.

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to see things if we split the function up into as many simple lines as we can and add debug `printf`'s:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[] = { 3, 5, 2, 6, 4 };
int level;

#define debug(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        for (int lvl = level << 1;  lvl > 0;  --lvl) \
            fputc(' ',stdout); \
        printf(_fmt); \
    } while (0)

static inline int
max(int x,int y)
{
    int ret;

    ret = (x > y) ? x : y;

    return ret;
}

int
f(int *p, int n)
{
    int pp;
    int val;
    int ret;

    debug("f: ENTER p=%p(%ld) n=%d level=%d\n",p,p - a,n,level);

    if (n <= 1)
        ret = 0;
    else {
        ++level;
        val = f(p + 1,n - 1);
        --level;

        pp = p[0] - p[1];
        debug("f: SUBVAL val=%d pp=%d\n",val,pp);
        ret = max(val,pp);
    }

    debug("f: EXIT ret=%d level=%d\n",ret,level);

    return ret;
}

int
main(void)
{
    printf("RESULT: %d\n", f(a, 5));
}
```

Here is the output:

```
f: ENTER p=0x601050(0) n=5 level=0
  f: ENTER p=0x601054(1) n=4 level=1
    f: ENTER p=0x601058(2) n=3 level=2
      f: ENTER p=0x60105c(3) n=2 level=3
        f: ENTER p=0x601060(4) n=1 level=4
        f: EXIT ret=0 level=4
      f: SUBVAL val=0 pp=2
      f: EXIT ret=2 level=3
    f: SUBVAL val=2 pp=-4
    f: EXIT ret=2 level=2
  f: SUBVAL val=2 pp=3
  f: EXIT ret=3 level=1
f: SUBVAL val=3 pp=-2
f: EXIT ret=3 level=0
RESULT: 3
```